# Passing a php variable from one form to another using $_POST

Tags: php

I am fairly new to PHP and I am having real trouble trying to make a variable used in one php page available to another using POST.  Here is a test file that I have been using.  All it does is pass the string in geronimo2, not the contents of the variable. Please could someone help point out how I have been dozy. Thanks.

```
<?php
$trying="just a string";
echo $trying;
?>

<form name="input" action="test2.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="geronimo2" style="display:none" value="$trying"></input>
<p align="center">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit My Information" />
</input>
</p>
</form>
```

Comment: why are you using `<input type="text" name="geronimo2" style="display:none"` insted of `<input type="hidden" name="geronimo2"`?

Comment: You don't need to close input tags. Plus you have a closing </p> tag in between your "submit" input. Also naming a form "input" is not wise. May cause conflicts.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
value="$trying"
```

to

```
value="<?php echo $trying;?>"
```

Comment: Or shorthand: value="<?=$trying?>"

Comment: Thank you for that, very helpful.  I had forgotten to end the php line with a ; when I tried that method.  My code is still very shakey, very new to php so I try and use knowledge from other languages to get a fast result.....

Comment: That's fine @user2333012. Don't forget to tick answer if it is resolved. Just to inform the stackoverflow rules. :)